# Can my Creative Cloud account be hacked and artwork stolen?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, creative-cloud

Is it possible for Adobe Creative Cloud to be hacked and my artwork stolen? If I create a design (Photoshop),save it to my desktop and no where else, is it still possible someone can steal my file because Adobe is cloud based? Or is Adobe not actually cloud based and only the software is?

Just need clarification.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a question for graphic designers, this may be better suited on [Security.SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Yes, in theory, **any** company can be hacked and artwork/info can be stolen.

Comment: I would assume, that Adobe has the proper measures and precautions in place, to avoid these sorts of situations.

Comment: @WELZ, there was that 2013 hack: https://www.theverge.com/2013/11/7/5078560/over-150-million-breached-records-from-adobe-hack-surface-online — One would hope it's more secure now.

Answer (score 2):

You have the choice whether you want your artwork and files to be saved just locally or saved locally and on the Creative Cloud network. Your Adobe programs are installed locally on your computer. What Creative Cloud does is sync your files for every device you use that has Creative Cloud synced. Your files could not be hacked from Creative Cloud if you do not put the files in a Creative Cloud synced folder.

From the [Adobe File storage and quota](https://helpx.adobe.com/creative-cloud/kb/file-storage-quota.html#)

> A Creative Cloud membership includes cloud-based storage, which allows
>   you to access files stored in the cloud from any computer using a web
>   browser or file sync functionality.

Answer (score 0):

In theory Adobe's software can have anything which is out of the control of ordinary users -  just like any software.

Adobe has a reason to keep a connection between your computer and their server. It's to prevent you to work without paying the rent. In theory they can at the same time copy all pixels and paths you have painted. But have they any believable reason to do it. I guess NO. But a criminal can try to use Adobe's connection for his purposes after he has got into Adobe's system.

I believe more dangerous are those who search your financial data, contacts, passwords etc or try to make your computer as a part of attack machinery or hidden illegal services server network. They have also a possiblity to steal your art. I guess they are more interested to encrypt it and get a ransom.

Adobe obviously has made some preventive measures to make their system difficult to enter. I think it's more probable that you will get persuaded to open the door by making a click in a wrong place.

So: keep your valuable data backed in a storage out of your computer and have at least 2 copies.

Answer (score 0):

## Yes

Your computer is connected to a network, therefore it is possible to hack you. Does not matter if you upload stuff on adobe cloud or only locally both can be hacked. Does not even change if you would use a offline program.

By putting files in the cloud you just expanded your attack surface.
The only difference is that the sync servers are a more valuable target for attack.